# The new help desk system ignores the network

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, contact

I recently raised a support request via the MSE contact us link for an issue involving another site (it's complicated and irrelevant). It lists the ticket as being for "stackoverflow.com". While I realise there are probably reasons for this - it seems it might be more accurate to refer to it as something like "Public Q&A".

[image: contact ticket with "stackoverflow.com" listed as "Stack Overflow Product"]

It would be nice to take this into account both here, and other network-wide support tools.

Comment: The title of this post alone is universal and worth an upvote.

Comment: Flagging for migration to Stack Overflow, because it’s the only site on the network. /joke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those fields seen in your screenshot shouldn't really have been visible to the end user — especially given you were able to edit them. We've since removed those, so aside from being able to rate your satisfaction (or actually respond to the ticket), you shouldn't be able to tinker around with ticket fields any more.

Comment: That's one way to sort it out :D . Wait. I could have set things to S1? Darn it... the missed opportunities.